# Debo indicar cuantas veces se encuentra el número mayor en el arreglo

Tags: c#

Debo colocar cuántas veces se repite el número mayor en el arreglo pero no me sale, traté de hacerlo con un contador como se ve en el código pero no resulto:(

```
int[] arr = new int[5];
Console.WriteLine("***** Introduce 10 números enteros *****");
int mayor = arr[0], j = 0;
int suma = 0;
                 
for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length ; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Introduce el número "+(i+1));
    arr[i]= int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    suma = suma + arr[i];    
}

int contMayor = 0;

while (j < arr.Length)
{
    if (arr[j] > mayor) mayor = arr[j]; j++;
            contMayor++;
}

Console.WriteLine("Promedio de los números positivos del vector es: " +(suma / 5));
Console.WriteLine("El número mayor del vector es: " + mayor + " y se repite: " + contMayor);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar **Linq** y de esta forma ahorrarás código y te será mas fácil de mantener:

```
int mayor = arr.Max();
```

Aquí usando el **método Max** obtendrás el mayor número del arreglo, una vez obtenido el mayor número del arreglo harías:

```
int repeticiones = arr.Count(a => a == mayor);

Console.WriteLine("El número mayor del vector es: " + mayor + " y se repite: " + repeticiones);
```

Aquí utilizando el **método Count** obtendremos la cantidad de veces que se repite el número mayor del arreglo previamente guardado en la **variable mayor**.

Para hacer uso de **Linq** debes poner en los **usings**:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: muchas gracias me sirvio mucho tu ayuda!! que estes bien

Answer (score 1):

No te sale, porque tu codigo no esta para nada ordenado...

Desglosemos el problema en español...

Te piden: "cuantas veces se repite el numero mayor en el arreglo".. Eso quiere decir que tengo que encontrar el mayor, y si lo vuelvo a encontrar, llevar la cantidad de veces que lo encontre... entonces, lo que tenemos que hacer es buscar el mayor, y despues contar cuantas veces aparece...

Vamos a desglosar tu codigo primero, solo la parte que "soluciona" el problema

```
//contador de las veces que encontre el mayor
int contMayor = 0;
//un for servia tambien, pero es valido
while (j < arr.Length)
{
    //como esto esta todo en una linea es dificil de entender, pero...
    //me fijo si el del array es mayor que mayor. 
    //si es mayor, cambio mayor, luego sumo j (es correcto)
    if (arr[j] > mayor) mayor = arr[j]; j++;
    //y ahora le sumo 1 al contador, siempre le sumo... no suena correcto
    contMayor++;
}
```

Ahora, porque siempre le sumas uno al contador? no deberias sumarle solo cuando mayor sea igual al del array???

es mas... si encuentro un nuevo mayor, el contador no deberia volver a 1???

Dicho todo esto, ya lo podes solucionar... reescribi esa parte, y listo!

De paso, vamos a ordenar tu codigo erroneo, solo para que se vea mejor...

```
int contMayor = 0;
while (j < arr.Length)
{
    if (arr[j] > mayor)
    {
        mayor = arr[j]; 
    }
    j++;
    contMayor++;
}
```